# About proof of "Exterior measure of a closed cube is equal to its volume".

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

I suppose my question is related to my basic misunderstanding of something.

Part of the proof:

[image]
In the proof we see "Since $Q$ covers itself, $\textbf{we must have } m^*(Q)\leq |Q|$...". Then we prove $m^*(Q)\geq |Q|$ and finish the proof.

My question is about first argument. How can infinum of coverings be less than volume? Why we write $m^*(Q)\leq |Q|$? Why $\textbf{we must have}$ it?

Where is an example when we can say that $m^*(Q)< |Q|$?

Edit: And if there is not such example why we can not simply state at the very start of the proof that $m^*(Q)= |Q|$?

Edit: If it was something like that "Let $Q^.$ will be any covering of $Q$ then we must have $m^*(Q)\leq |Q^.|$." And it is ok with me. But in the proof we take precisely the $Q$.

Comment: What's the _definition_ of $m_*(Q)$?

Comment: The exterior measure of $Q$ is $$m^*(Q)=inf\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|Q_{j}|$$

Comment: Where $(Q_j)$ is some cover of $Q$.

Comment: Any cover can not be smaller then $Q$. And why infinum of all them must be less then $Q$?

Comment: If $S$ is any set of numbers and $s\in S$ then $\inf S\le s$ by definition. So if $(Q_j)$ is any open cover of $Q$ then $m_*(Q)\le\sum|Q_j|$. That's true for _any_ open cover; if you consider the open cover given by the single cube $Q$ it says $m_*(Q)\le|Q|$.

Comment: Now I grasp the idea. Thanks